# How to import time in HH:MM format in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a dataset as follows,

```
Date,Time,ID,Name,Count

01-MAY-2009,00:00,4,Town Hall (West),209

01-MAY-2009,02:00,17,Collins Place (South),28

01-MAY-2009,23:00,18,Collins Place (North),36
```

For this I have created table with following schema,

```
CREATE TABLE table_name(date DATE, time TIME, id int, name VARCHAR(50), count int);
```

And for loading the table from ".csv" file as,

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/home/cloudera/dataset.csv' 
INTO TABLE table_name
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
(@var1, @var2, id, name, count) 
SET date = STR_TO_DATE(@var1, '%d-%b-%Y') 
SET time = TIME(@var2, "%H:%i");
```

But I get an error as,

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET time = TIME(@var2, "%H:%i")' at line 1
```

I can't understand what the error is. I have tried going through MySQL website and documentation, but can't make out what the correct format is. Can anyone please me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that you even need to be using the `TIME` function here.  Your current `hour:minute` string time literals should be good enough, q.v. the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time.html):

> Be careful about assigning abbreviated values to a TIME column. MySQL interprets abbreviated TIME values with colons as time of the day. That is, '11:12' means '11:12:00', not '00:11:12'

As valid literals, your times would be interpreted as having a zero second component.  So, if you just insert those time strings as is, I think it should work.  Try the following code:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/home/cloudera/dataset.csv' 
INTO TABLE table_name
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
(@var1, Time, id, name, count) 
SET date = STR_TO_DATE(@var1, '%d-%b-%Y');
```

Comment: Is there any way to make MySQL interpret the Time values in HH:MM format?

Comment: @JohnDeer `HH:MM` is the format in which your time strings are already being interpreted (I think).

Comment: So, will MySQL not add "seconds" literal to time?

Comment: @JohnDeer AFAIK internally all time is recorded in seconds, or something similar to this.  Because your time literals don't specify a seconds component, MySQL will assume that there are zero seconds, on that minute and on that hour.

Comment: When I retrieved the table contents, seconds component was added. Is there any way not to add seconds component to time. Basically, I don't want it for my analysis purpose.

Comment: I think there needs to be a seconds component.  If you don't want to _see_ the seconds, well you can just use a string function to remove them from the output.

Comment: @JohnDeer By the way, your initial code was almost spot on...you asked a very good first question, miles beyond what usually happens on SO :-)

Answer (score 0):

Tim is right in pointing out that you do not need to convert your time data in the `load data infile` statement.

Just to answer why you get a syntax error: `load data infile` can only have a single `set` clause, in which assignments to multiple columns are separated by comma. Your code has multiple `set` clauses, hence it fails.

Also, the `time()` function does not have a 2nd parameter for a pattern. The function you need to use is called [str_to_date()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date).

So, it should look like as follows:

```
...
SET date = STR_TO_DATE(@var1, '%d-%b-%Y'), time = TIME(str_to_date(@var2, "%H:%i"));
```

Comment: But with the solution suggested, I get date in "YYYY-MM-DD" format. I want the date to be in "DD-MMM-YYYY". I want 3 character month name as "Jan". Is it possible?

Comment: I have the same answer as Tim provided around not displaying the seconds: you can format the date as you want when you query your table.

Comment: You didn't get me. When I load the contents of the file in table, they are being loaded as "2009-05-01", but not as "01-May-2009". I want to load contents in table in that way. Is it possible?

Comment: No, you did not get me. That's a display issue only. You must format the date when you query it.